# avoiding full singular value decomposition of matrix

Tags: python, svd

I need to compute the first singular value of a matrix with the corresponding left and right eigenvectors. Is there a way in Python to avoid computing full singular value decomposition of a matrix in order to extract its greatest singular value?

Comment: Does this relate?
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7566/memory-efficient-implementations-of-partial-singular-value-decompositions-svd

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you are intending to obtain. Do you mean one of the following?

1) If what you want is to simply extract the first value of the matrices product, this works for me:

```
Ua,Sa,Va=np.linalg.svd(A) #Changing A for your matrix.

U=Ua[1,0]
S=Sa[0]
V=Va[1,0]
```

2) If, on the other hand, what your intending to do is to pause the SVD once it has found the largest singular value, I do not think it would be possible, given that Singular Value Decomposition is the product of three matrices, and even if what you are looking for is the highest Singular Value, the SVD would have to run fully to obtain it.
Also, the first element of the SV diagonal matrix is not necessarily the first to be computed.